# Unable to add react component in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I've tried to convert my react component to a html file and then put it inside a pdf using jspdf, but I can't seem to make it work. Here's my code:

```
 pdf.fromHTML(
  ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<DanishReport />),
  10,
  10,
  { width: 180 }
);
```

The DanishReport component contains a simple div and a header text. I get the following message:

> "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '1' of
>   undefined"